# Query Parameters in URL from a Rails form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, query-string

I have a filter sidebar that starts with a Rails `form_tag` and contains a range slider and a bunch of `check_box_tag`.

It posts and filters fine.  It even persists on the next page as I render it with the checkbox values.

However, if you refresh the page, or send a link to someone, the filters are lost.

The only way I've seen how to do it is to use `redirect_to` and merge the params, but I'd rather not make a second call.

How can I pass all the options as query params?

[image: A range slider with a list of checkbox filters]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you're not creating anything I would recommend using `GET` requests with query string parameters. So the query can be shared with the url.

Url for your example image would be something like:

```
http://www.yourwebsite.com/?max_price=5
```

Which gives you a `params[:max_price]` in controller.